# Existing solo DnD campaigns to use with a novice player?

Tags: game-recommendation, dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures

Are there any recommendations for premade solo adventures for DnD I could use to DM for my wife as a solo campaign?

She's a total novice to role-playing, so I'd like to focus on the exploration and interaction elements a bit more than the brawling. As such, most editions would be fine. I'm planning on either playing 3.5e with lots of hand-waving to eliminate complexity, or diving into 5e. I can spend some time swapping out encounters and such, though, as long as that's the primary task in converting to a different edition.

I'd also prefer modules that are more exploration-and-interaction based. I feel like that would work better for a solo player, and plays to her interests better than a dungeon crawling hack-and-slash (combat is fine, but only as a means to an end, not 85% of the adventure).

My desired setting is pretty fluid, too. She's new enough that establishing the setting as Forgotten Realms or Dragonlance would be irrelevant, as she lacks the meta-knowledge to make use of that detail.

Free adventures on someone's blog are just as admissible as a paid module from WOTC or found in an issue of Dragon Magazine.

---

As this is a "shopping question", please feel free to let me know if I need more narrow criteria to prevent this from being over-broad.

Answer (score 4):

I have run several of the HHQ series AD&D 2e modules and they worked out very well.  I specifically remember Cleric's Challenge (1? 2?) that I used when a fighter PC had converted to cleric and was trying to figure out what that was like... He went to this little winery town to rebuild the church there and got embroiled in all the small-town social stuff.  There was a monster in the end (won't say what because of spoilers) but a lot of the time spent was counseling kids that wanted to elope, trying to get the family rivalries in check, etc.

A friend ran a batch of the [Expeditious Retreat Press 1 on 1 Pathfinder solo adventures](http://paizo.com/products/btpy89ux?One-on-One-Adventures-Compendium) for his son, who was taking up roleplaying. He liked them but they are a *lot* more fight/dungeoney - though there's a bunch of them and they vary in type and tone, up to full on parody (The Pleasure Prison of the B'thuvian Demon Whore). Some are explorey but definitly with fights.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say what's good, but here are the options I am aware of.

BD&D Truly solo adventures: DMless choose your own adventure style modules.

1. [Lathan's Gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lathan%27s_Gold)
2. [Blizzard Pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blizzard_Pass)
3. [Maze of the Riddling Minotaur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_of_the_Riddling_Minotaur)
4. [Thunderdelve Mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderdelve_Mountain)

AD&D 2nd Ed Class specific modules [Head to Head Quest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_D%26D_modules#H) series, actually 1 on 1

Pathfinder 3rd party [1 on 1 Adventures](http://paizo.com/products/btpy89ux?One-on-One-Adventures-Compendium). Pathfinder is very close to D&D 3.5.

Comment: Hi Drew. We do have a rule about shopping questions: answers must be based on experience. This rule was created because shopping answers used to become a long list of low-quality suggestions of personal favourites and "I think this might work". Have you used any of these for one-on-one play?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I did consider that, but my reasoning was that this is a very specific request with not many possible answers. There just aren't that many D&D modules aimed at 1 player. However, if you disagree with my reasoning, let me know. I will defer and delete my answer.